# How to declare global variable that reads the last line of richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, variables, global, declaration, public

I have this code

```
    Dim totalLines As Integer = frmTerminal.rtbDisplay.Lines.Length
    Dim lastLine As String = frmTerminal.rtbDisplay.Lines(totalLines - 1)
```

That code effectively reads the last line of my richtextbox and it is very useful to all of my functions.

**Problem:**

Because most of my functions rely on detecting the last line of a richtextbox I would like to declare it as global and public variable. But whenever I make it global and public it result in an error stating that

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in xxxxxx.exe

It means something like I want to count the lines of a not yet created richtextbox, so my **`question`** is how do I effectively get the lastline of a richtextbox in a global and public way?

Comment: A global declaration like this would be bad practice.

Comment: @paul Can you please tell me why?

Comment: Technically the information is already easily available to you from the control itself and has a particular scope in your application. Why would everything else in the whole app need to know about this value? At most, you should limit the variable to the scope of you current form, or follow Mort and Pradeep's lead on exposing a property.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a public property

```
Public ReadOnly Property LastLine() As String
    Get
        Dim returnValue As String = String.Empty
        If rtbDisplay.Lines.Count > 0 Then
            returnValue = rtbDisplay.Lines(rtbDisplay.Lines.Count - 1)
        End If
        Return returnValue
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

While declaring it as public variable may not help, you can declare it as a public property in your class.

```
Public ReadOnly Property LastLine() As String
    Get
        Return frmTerminal.rtbDisplay.Lines(frmTerminal.rtbDisplay.Lines.Length - 1)
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: What do you mean by it will not help Sir? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: If you just use public variable you will need to call some method to refresh its value before you use it. That's what a public property or a public method does (i.e. allow you to execute some code). You cant achieve this purely with a public variable.